# Find and Replace Whole Words (not substrings) in Emacs

Tags: regex, emacs, replace

1) In my process of adjusting from my GUI editor to EMACS I seem to have trouble finding a clear-cut way to do a relatively simple task for most editors: Find and replace whole words (non-substrings) within a text and find exact matches. M-x replace-string finds substrings as well as whole words. Is there a regexp that does this?

2) Also, is there a way to match exact strings? For example if I wanted to replace myClaSs with the exact case for each letter what would I have to do? Right now the replace-string matches myclass with myCLasS. As I udnerstand only the first letters in the case are matched. I'm assuming some regexp takes care of this also.

3) Is there an option to do a wrap-around search? Or will I always have to decide whether I do C-s (forward) or C-r (backward)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use word boundary anchors: `\bfoo\b` only matches `foo`, not `foobar`.

Then, regular expressions usually are case-sensitive. In most flavors, you can explicitly make them case-sensitive by prepending `(?I)` or `(?-i)` to your regex. But I'm not sure if Emacs regexes can do that.

I have no idea about your third question. Sorry.

Comment: `M-<` executes `beginning-of-buffer`

Comment: In addition, `beginning-of-buffer` pushes point to the local mark ring, and so do the search/replace commands. Therefore, after you've finished replacing, you can use `C-u SPC` (which pops the local mark ring) twice to return to where you started.

Answer (score 6):

All the other answers provide information you can use to get Emacs to do what you want.  But you can also roll your own search/replace function to do what you want like so:

```
(defun search-replace-ala-octi (tosearch toreplace)
  (interactive "sSearch for word: \nsReplace with: ")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((case-fold-search nil)
          (count 0))
      (while (re-search-forward (concat "\\b" tosearch "\\b") nil t)
        (setq count (1+ count))
        (replace-match toreplace 'fixedcase 'literal))
      (message "Replaced %s match(es)" count))))
```

And bind it to whatever key you want...

Comment: The more I want to learn EMACS the more I realize I have to learn LISP instead.

Comment: @octi Most of getting Emacs to do what you want is just learning Emacs - which happens to be lisp.  95% of what folks want is just customizing the hooks/variables that are already there.  The other 5% can be found by asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, can you please put multiple questions into separate questions in the future?  It makes it easier for others to help you and for other users who have some of the same questions in the future to get help from past answers.

1. See @Tim's answer
2. See `C-h k M-%` and read the section about case matching
3. Doing `C-s` after the last match will prompt you that you're at the end, hitting `C-s` *again* will wrap from the beginning.  Read the docs by hitting `C-h i` then click on `* Emacs` then hit `g Repeat Isearch RET`, second to last paragraph.

Comment: M-% is working good in conjunction with the "!" modifier to not stop at every match. I am still learning emacs syntax and would like to know how I can request the prefix/optional args for commands. in this case the DELIMITED argument of M-%. (Third arg DELIMITED (prefix arg if interactive), if non-nil, means replace
only matches surrounded by word boundaries.)

Comment: That sounds like another question.  :-)  I'm not clear what you're asking here.  Open another question and elaborate there.

Comment: Well the question was how to set DELIMITED to non-nil when calling M-%. I did open another question though. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For question 2, if the search string is all lower-case, emacs does a case-insensitive search by default. You can force it to do a case-sensitive search by setting `case-fold-search` to nil. You can put this in your .emacs file: `(setq case-fold-search nil)`.

Answer (score 1):

On question 1 (whole word search)
`\b` in @Tim 's answer cannot work when meeting the character `_`. It seems that `foo\b` can match `foo_bar` in Emacs (of course it cannot match in Perl).

Comment: It all depends upon the buffer's syntax table (which is set by the major mode in the majority of cases). If `_` is not a word constituent character in the syntax table, then `\b` might match either side of it, as in your example. Note that in Emacs regexps, you can match the beginning or end of a *symbol* with `\_<` and `\_>` respectively (`_` is almost certainly a symbol constituent in perl-mode).